# Get specific dates for offer

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I need to get specific dates for all offers in one SQL-Query. I don't know how to do that with these conditions:

1. If there is a *active offer*, I need the Start-/Enddates of the *active period*
2. If there is a *expired offer*, I need the *last* Start-/Enddates
3. If there is a *future offer*, I need the *first* Start-/Enddates

**Table Offer:**

```
OfferID Name
10      Current Offer
20      Expired Offer
30      Coming Offer
```

**Table OfferDates:** (NULL = endless offer)

```
OfferID StartDate   EndDate
10      2000-01-01  2009-12-31
10      2010-01-01  NULL        //Need this (1.)
20      1900-01-01  1900-12-31
20      1901-01-01  1901-12-31  //Need this (2.)
30      2030-01-01  2030-12-31  //Need this (3.)
30      2031-01-01  NULL
```

**This should be the result:**

```
OfferID Name    StartDate   EndDate
10      Current 2010-01-01  NULL
20      Expired 1901-01-01  1901-12-31
30      Coming  2030-01-01  2030-12-31
```

**This will give me the active offers (1.):**

```
SELECT o.Name, d.StartDate, d.EndDate FROM Offer AS o
LEFT JOIN OfferDates AS d ON o.OfferID = d.OfferID
WHERE d.StartDate <= GETDATE() AND (d.EndDate IS NULL OR d.EndDate > GETDATE())
```

I hope that someone can help me!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it!

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
o.Name,  
ISNULL(curr.StartDate, ISNULL(fut.StartDate, hist.StartDate)) AS 'StartDate', --Only get "NOT NULL-StartDate"
ISNULL(curr.EndDate, ISNULL(fut.EndDate, hist.EndDate)) AS 'EndDate' --Only get "NOT NULL-EndDate"

FROM Offer AS o

-- Current
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM OfferDates WHERE StartDate <= GETDATE() AND (EndDate IS NULL OR  EndDate > GETDATE())) AS curr ON (o.OfferID = curr.OfferID)

-- Expired
LEFT JOIN (SELECT OfferID, MAX(EndDate) AS EndDate FROM OfferDates WHERE EndDate < GETDATE()  AND EndDate IS NOT NULL GROUP BY OfferID)AS tmpHist ON (o.OfferID = tmpHist.OfferID)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM OfferDates WHERE OfferID NOT IN (SELECT OfferID FROM OfferDates WHERE EndDate >= GETDATE() OR EndDate IS NULL)) AS hist ON (tmpHist.OfferID = hist.OfferID AND tmpHist.EndDate = hist.EndDate)

-- Future
LEFT JOIN (SELECT OfferID, MIN(StartDate) AS StartDate FROM OfferDates WHERE StartDate > GETDATE() GROUP BY OfferID) AS tmpFut ON (o.OfferID = tmpFut.OfferID)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM OfferDates WHERE OfferID NOT IN (SELECT OfferID FROM OfferDates WHERE StartDate <= GETDATE())) AS fut ON (tmpFut.OfferID = o.OfferID AND tmpFut.StartDate = fut.StartDate)
```